# Elasticsearch 5 multi value and multi field search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do a search with multiple fields and one of the fields has multiple exact match values. This is how I would do it in SQL.

```
select * from logs
where order_id IN (123, 456)
and ( message LIKE 'Order fetched%' OR message LIKE 'Tax allocated%');
```

Super confused on how to do this in elastic 5.x

My mapping is this.

```
"properties" : {
    "company_id" : { "type" : "long"},
    "order_id" : { "type" : "long"},
    "sku_id" : { "type" : "long"},
    "piece_id" : { "type" : "long"},
    "item_titles_order_id" : { "type" : "long"},
    "type" : { "type" : "keyword"},
    "message" : { "type" : "text"},
    "created" : { "type" : "date", "ignore_malformed" : true, "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SQL WHERE AND / OR` logic can be translated to [bool queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

`SQL IN` filter can be translated to [terms queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) which operate on non analysed fields

`SQL LIKE` operator can be translated to [wildcard queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) which operate on non analysed fields

Putting everything together, you can try something like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [  // SQL AND 
        {
          "terms": {  // SQL IN
            "order_id": [123, 456]
          }
        }, 
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [ // SQL OR
              {
                "wildcard": {  // SQL LIKE
                  "message": "Order fetched*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "message": "Tax allocated*'"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You may need to change the type of the `message` field to `keyword` or to create a subfield of type `keyword` for this field.

Comment: Does not seem to work, unless I am doing something wrong. The query you mentioned returned an empty result. Also, the following 2 queries returned empty results. `{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [  
        {
          "terms": {  
            "order_id": [4418316051, 4418316051]
          }
        }        
      ]
    }
  }
}` and `{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [  
        {
          "terms": {  
            "order_id": [4418316051]
          }
        }        
      ]
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Are you sure those `order_id` are present in the index ? Can you try this request `{"query": { "match": { "order_id": 4418316051} } }`. If the `order_id` is present, it should return a document